# iOS UIScrollView with multiple pages visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm having a little issue with scrollview pagination.

My intention is to have 3 pages visible on screen and when I scroll right only on page is scrolled, following the example below, scrolling right will display page 2, 3 and 4 on screen:

[image: scrollview]

However I don't know how to display mutiple pages at the same time, at the moment I have it like this:

[image: now]

Obviously like this is not what I want.

To achieve the desired functionality I tried making the scrollview's frame the size of the page I want (1/3 of the screen width) and setting the clipToBound to NO so the other pages are visible. This indeed shows 3 pages in the screen; however since the scrollview frame is only 1/3 of the screen I can only swipe in that area, I would like the swipe area to be the whole screen width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution in the end was the following:

- I took my initial approach.
- I disabled the scrollview's scrollEnabled property.
- Added swipe gesture recognisers to the scrollview.
- When the gesture is made I modify the scrollview's contentOffset to move 320/3 pixels to the right or left.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right path. Now you can try manipulating `UIPanGestureRecognizer` of your scrollView, say, re-attaching it to scrollView's superview.

Alternatively, take a look at [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel), it can be perfectly customized to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kyr, unfortunately I have multiple scrollViews in the same view, so attaching the gesture recognizer to the superview will bind all the scrollViews together.